# How to intercept a URL with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am currently importing a third party HTML file into my page and it has following java script method tied to a form submit.

```
function ValidateInput(){
       //some code
        if(validationFailed){       
               alert("Validation failed");
                return false;
            }else{   
                return openWin("URL");
        }
    }
```

I don't have control over this code. But I want to intercept the URL that is mentioned in the ***openWin*** function and I want to do some validation on that URL before it opens.
Is it possible with JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery.

You can replace the function with your own and call the old one if you want.

```
var oldOpenWin = openWin;
openWin = function(url) {
    // do validation
    // call old one
    oldOpenWin(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite any function like so:

```
(function(original_openWin) {
  window.openWin = function() {
    // your own code
    alert('Hello world from openWin intercept');

    // execute original openWin function
    original_openWin();
  }
})(openWin);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hyadC/